# iOS Registrations disappear after reinstalling several times and then sending a notification

Tags: ios, azure, notifications

This issue is not the same with '[Azure Notification Hub registrations disappear when sending a notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190777/azure-notification-hub-registrations-disappear-when-sending-a-notification)'.

First of all, I can make sure it is not a certification issue. Because normally it can receive the notification without any problem.

The process to reproduce the issue:

1. Install the app and register the push notification. (We can see 1 record from the 'Service Bus Explorer')
2. Uninstall the app
3. Reinstall the app and register the push notification
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 several times (we can see some registrations from the 'Service Bus Explorer')
5. Send a notification
6. Sometimes, all the registrations disappear. Sometimes, the last one will be left.

Does anyone have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

All registrations disappearing indicate that the APNS rejects the device token. Make sure the below
1.you are getting token from physical device (not emulator)

2.APNS certificate uploaded to NH is not expired

3.APNS certificate uploaded to NH corresponds to APNS endpoint you are using in application

Thanks,
Amol

Comment: Hi Amol,

Thanks for your response. The case here is notification working correctly for the first several re-installations. The issue happened after some re-installations and all historical registrations including the last one gone.

I mean even in the conditions: physical device / certificate not expired / certificate matched, the issue can still happen.